# Disable auto Vertical Scroll for scrollIntoView() upon thumbnail refresh

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, sass

I have an Image Gallery Slider that uses ScrollIntoView() for its thumbnail, but every time I scroll up or down the page and the newest thumbnail is selected, it brings the entire page location back to where the thumbnail sits. Is there a way to disable this scrollIntoView() feature? The project is: https://codepen.io/abcretrograde/pen/povVxVq

```
    function updateImage() {
  const thumbs = document.querySelectorAll(
    "#jsSlideshow .js-slideshow__thumb-image"
  );
  clearInterval(autoUpdate);
  autoUpdate = setInterval(() => {
    incImage();
  }, slideSpeed);
  const newOffset = getImagePos(imageWidthArray, whichImage);
  slideshow.style.setProperty("--offset", newOffset + "px");
  thumbs.forEach((thumb) => {
    thumb.classList.remove("js-slideshow__thumb-image--selected");
  });
  thumbs[whichImage].classList.add("js-slideshow__thumb-image--selected");
  thumbs[whichImage].scrollIntoView({
    behavior: "auto",
    block: 'center',
    inline: "center",
  });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `block` property - `scrollIntoView(options)` - defines vertical alignment.

Have you tried changing `center` to `nearest`?

```
  thumbs[whichImage].scrollIntoView({
    behavior: "auto", 
    block: "nearest",
    inline: "center"
  });
```